# Unable to boot, UUID does not exist

Tags: boot, partitioning, uuid

I am a new Linux user; I've consulted other forum posts to the best of my ability but I have not been able to figure this issue out on my own.

This is a Dell Inspiron 7856, recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (removed Windows entirely after testing out features from live). It operated fine the first few days, and I have not messed with the terminal much besides installing basic program packages. As of recently, I cannot boot into the OS. There is some delay on the screen and then it displays the message:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
```

...

```
ALERT! UUID=4d71a352-fbe5-4718-b71f-f71a6c0fd37b does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Easy solutions: I have not changed any BIOS settings besides those required for installation and I am not using a VM. Can confirm AHCI is enabled and secure boot disabled.

I am now in live mode from the USB I used to install. I am unsure if I have to access/reassign the UUIDs in question but when I search for them I only see UUIDs from the flash drive, to my understanding.

**blkid**

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2022-04-19-10-23-19-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb2-91e0a90189a1"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="8D6C-A9F8" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb1-91e0a90189a1"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="writable" UUID="b3355d14-1ea5-4c5b-be3e-44e62dcafb3f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ab0aadc3-1a3f-7b4a-92e6-09b13e35d629"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb0-91e0a90189a1"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
```

**/dev/disk/by-uuid**

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 03:36 2022-04-19-10-23-19-00 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 03:36 8D6C-A9F8 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 03:36 b3355d14-1ea5-4c5b-be3e-44e62dcafb3f -> ../../sda4
```

I only see UUIDs from different /sda#s. All of /dev/sda belongs to my flash drive according to fdisk. (Is this because I am in live mode, do I need to access the terminal differently?)

**fdisk**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.33 GiB, 2502324224 bytes, 4887352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 248.76 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 155.63 MiB, 163188736 bytes, 318728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 81.26 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 43.63 MiB, 45748224 bytes, 89352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.92 GiB, 16018046976 bytes, 31285248 sectors
Disk model: USB Flash Drive 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A09DB2B8-B5F6-43AE-AFB3-91E0A90189A1

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       64  7129427  7129364  3.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  7129428  7137923     8496  4.1M EFI System
/dev/sda3  7137924  7138523      600  300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  7139328 31285184 24145857 11.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 45.86 MiB, 48087040 bytes, 93920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
$ ls -lh /mnt/etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37 Apr 19 06:02 /mnt/etc/fstab
$ cat /mnt/etc/fstab
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
```

I was having some trouble finding the root partition due to `/dev/sda` being occupied by the USB, but I followed [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Finding_your_root_partition) to confirm its location on `/dev/loop0`. This is my new result after mounting it.

Also may be of note: when I click through the installer steps as if I were to re-install Ubuntu, it skips the step of asking me whether I want to install instead of / alongside the current OS and goes straight into custom partitioning, but only shows me a table underneath /dev/sda with a total of 16 GB to work with (size of flash drive).

Please let me know what other information I can provide / what commands used to do so and I will update my post. Thank you if you read this far; as I said much of this is new to me but I am trying to use it as a learning experience.

Comment: Looks like an edit will need to be made to the `/etc/fstab` file, which contains a list of partitions to mount at boot time. Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of that file? This will make it easier for someone to offer a specific suggestion 

Comment: Thank you @matigo, I have updated with the fstab contents.

Comment: The `fstab` you are showing in your question is the `fstab` *from the live USB file system*. We need to see the `fstab` that is *installed on the device*. You should mount the / partition from the device, and show us the `fstab` from there.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but I have now corrected that section. It definitely looks like the source of the issue to me.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue @velvetant? I have the exact same issue. How did you find the root partition and how were you able to restore it?

Comment: @NielsUitterdijk Sadly, I never found a solution. I suspect my laptop may have had latent hardware issues/damage, as with all my hours of effort I was never able to boot into Ubuntu -- or even revert to Windows -- despite never doing anything irreversible. The keyboard did get a little splash of water once, weeks earlier. I built a new PC rather than spend money repairing a years-old laptop, as I had done all I could on my own. Hopefully you have better luck; there are other posts describing similar problems. If you find a fix I might try it though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Think I've tried all posts out there without luck. Eventually ran a full diagnostics from BIOS, which indicated problems with the video card. Which seems odd, but does point towards a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to a specific problem here:

My Acer Aspire Laptop uses the Intel RST and Optane technology. Ubuntu is not able to work with RST.

When I installed Ubuntu, I already set it to AHCI, but 2 weeks ago I suspect a Windows update reset the UEFI back to default. I got the same error messages, because Ubuntu could not find the / partition.

Here‘s how to set the Acer UEFI from RST to AHCI, if you have the same one:

1. Boot into the UEFI
2. (For many options you need to set a supervisor password on the last page. I set it anyway, I don‘t know if it is required in this case. Set an easy one like 12345, because you won‘t be able to „password forget“ if you forget it.)
3. Go to the second page and press Ctrl+S on your keyboard at the same time. An option will appear in the middle between other options, that lets you change „RST“ to „AHCI“.
4. Save and reboot.

After that, Ubuntu booted normally, as well as Windows.